# Jsonp Callback error

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, json

Recently we have started migrating application from Javascript API 3.1 to 3.5 and we are finding this jsonp error coming sometimes during adding the layer.When we add the layer we also zoom to the layer .Below is the snapshot of the error I get.

[image: Jsonp Error]

Comment: Try the ArcGIS API 3.5 Javascript JSONP Content example sandbox for comparing your code - http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=data_requestjsonp

Comment: Are you accessing a layer that's not on your server? If so, it could be a cross-origin issue

Comment: @raykendo all feature layer is on my server and application is also running on same server.